# Extracting hours from a csv with pandas

Tags: python, time, pandas

I have a csv that looks like this

```
time,result
1308959819,1
1379259923,2
1318632821,3
1375216682,2
1335930758,4
```

times are in unix format. I want to extract the hours from such times and groupby the file with respect to such values.

I tried

```
times = pd.to_datetime(df.time, unit='s')
```

or even

```
times = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime(df.time, unit='s'))
```

but in both cases I got an error with

```
times.hour
>>>AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because Series and DataFrames don't have `hour` attributes.  You can access the information you want using the `.dt` convenience accessor (docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/api.html#datetimelike-properties)):

```
>>> times = pd.to_datetime(df.time, unit='s')
>>> times
0   2011-06-24 23:56:59
1   2013-09-15 15:45:23
2   2011-10-14 22:53:41
3   2013-07-30 20:38:02
4   2012-05-02 03:52:38
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>> times.dt
<pandas.tseries.common.DatetimeProperties object at 0xb5de94c>
>>> times.dt.hour
0    23
1    15
2    22
3    20
4     3
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin [datetime](https://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) class to do this.

```
import datetime

# your code here

hours = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(df.time).hour
```